# Which is most likely the acidic proton in ascorbyl palmitate?

Tags: acid-base

The structure of ascrobyl palmitate contains a vinyl group, so I assume the red proton would be:
[image]

Comment: What about the other OH group on the other side of the double bond?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***The other H (hydrogen) will be more acidic***. The ascorbate anion is stabilized by electron delocalization, as I have show below in terms of resonance between two canonical forms.

[image: ascorbate anion resonance]